# Foreach on IEnumerable<> with if condition

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code :

```
IEnumerable<Vehicles> Vehicles;

for (int count = 0; count < Vehicles.Count(); count++)
{
    if (Vehicles.ElementAt(count).Mode)
    {

    }
}
```

How can i implement Lambda expression foreach with if condition also?

I tried this :

```
Vehicles.ToList().ForEach(i=>i.Mode)
```

And struck with this since I dont know how to check conditions since intellisense not showing where clause as well. any help much appreciated. And I would like to use the count value inside looping as well....

Comment: Very inefficient. If `Vehicles` is not a list or array `Vehicles.Count()` enumerates the whole query to calculate the count. Even worse is using  `ElementAt` in the loop since that is also enumerating the whole sequence until it is at the given index, but even on every iteration.

Comment: Basically, don't. Use a normal `foreach` loop, with a `Where` query: `foreach (var vehicle in Vehicles.Where(v => v.Mode))`

Comment: Is `Vehicles.Where(x => x.Mode).ToList().ForEach(x => { // do something with x })` what you're after?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve in the iteration?  It looks like `.Where()` or `.Select()` would do...

Comment: What do you mean by "implement lambda expression foreach"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume `Mode` is a `bool` property. Then you just need this little query and a `foreach`:

```
foreach(Vehicles v in Vehicles.Where(x => x.Mode))
{
    // do something with it
}
```

Your approach is very inefficient. If `Vehicles` is not a list or array `Vehicles.Count()` enumerates the whole query to calculate the count. Even worse is using  `ElementAt` in the loop since that is also enumerating the whole sequence until it is at the given index, but even for every iteration.

The last approach using `Vehicles.ToList().ForEach` is creating a new list for no obvious reason, just to be able to use the `ForEach` method which has no advantage over a plain `foreach`-loop. It also filters not the vehicles by this property.

If you need a counter as commented you just need to increase a local variable:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(Vehicles v in Vehicles.Where(x => x.Mode))
{
    count++;
    // do something with it
}
```

or select the index directly in the LINQ query into an anonymous type:

```
var modeVehicles = Vehicles
    .Where(x => x.Mode)
    .Select((x, index) => new { Count = index + 1, Vehicle = x });
foreach(var x in modeVehicles)
{
    int count = x.Count;
    Vehicles v = x.Vehicle;
    // do something with it
}
```

Both approaches return the number of vehicles which match the predicate(`Mode` is `true`).

If you instead want the number of this vehicle among all vehicles(including the non-matching) you have three options:

1.) use a for-loop if it's actually a list or array(to be preferred in that case):

```
var list = Vehicles as IList<Vehicles>;
if(list != null)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < list.Count; count++)
    {
        if (list[count].Mode)
        {
            // do something with it
        }
    }
}
```

2.) use a plain `foreach` and an `if`:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(Vehicles v in Vehicles)
{
    if (v.Mode)
    {
        // do something with it
    }
    count++;
}
```

3.) or a LINQ query like this (note that the index is selected first before the `Where`):

```
var modeVehicles = Vehicles
    .Select((x, index) => new { Count = index + 1, Vehicle = x })
    .Where(x => x.Mode);
foreach (var x in modeVehicles)
{
    int count = x.Count;
    Vehicles v = x.Vehicle;
    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: And I would like to use the count value inside looping as well....how to use the count variable? Please help me

Comment: @curiousDev: so you need to know the number of the current vehicle in the loop? Then use a local `int`-variable which you increase in the `foreach`. If you need that regardless whether the `Mode`-property is `true` or `false` you should simply use a `foreach`-loop (or `for` if it's a list or array) and use an `if` in the loop. That's the easiest and most efficient way.

Comment: I am not looking for number of vehicle count. On which vehicle (i mean if its first or third vehicle), need to display message accordingly based on bool value

Comment: @curiousDev: still not clear, if you have three vehicles and the second's `Mode` is `true`, which number do you need? One, two and three(so for every vehicle regardless of the property), only two(because that's the one with `Mode=true`) or only one (because there is only one where this property is `true`)?

Comment: if its second vehicle, i want 2

Comment: @curiousDev: then look at my edited answer. You just need a variable which you increase in the loop.

Comment: It wont work right...If its second vehicle i want count=2, but in the above code it will count =1

Comment: @curiousDev: edited my answer. The last part beginning with "if you instead want" is for you.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want as long as you don't need the count variable for anything

```
foreach (var vehicle in Vehicles.Where(v=>v.Mode))
{
    //do stuff with vehicle
}
```

Comment: I would like the count variable inside if condition check

Comment: @curiousDev, good point.  If you need an index into the entire Vehicles list then you had the right code at the start, and there is no need to use a lambda.  If you only want a new number for each of the vehicles that match the condition then add a local variable
    
  var count=0; 
foreach (var vehicle in Vehicles.Where(v=>v.Mode))
{
    //do stuff with vehicle
    ++count;
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
var qry = from v in Vehicles
          where v.Something == ?
          select v.Mode
```

qry is now an enumerable of only v.Mode's where your criteria is true.

Comment: There's no indication that the OP only wants `v.Mode`. That's the condition, in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add extension method

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Action<int, T> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in @this)
        action(i++, item);
}
```

then you can write in linq-style (stacking things on the right side), to example:

```
Vehicles.ForEach((index, vehicle) =>
{
    if(vehicle.Mode)
        Console.WriteLine($"{vehicle} index {index} is ok");
});
```

Note you can't use `Where` before such `ForEach` or you get wrong index value.

P.S.: I'll leave extending `ForEach` on the right side as a homework for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found this way. Thanks to Tim Schmelter. With your guidance, found this answer.
Thanks to all who tried helping me.

```
             Vehicles.Where(v => v.Mode== true)
                     .ToList()
                     .ForEach(v => 
                     {

                      });
```

This worked.

Answer (score -2):

```
Vehicle.tolist().where(I => I.example == condition). Tolist();
```

Or use .where (s => s.mode).Tolist();
This is just an example condition in the where check for what you want to condition for